# How to update/alter database values using ajax call with out page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner in mvc and am developing an ecommerce website.
In my cart list i need to enter specific quantity to calculate the total price with out page refresh. 
I used a java script call inside the foreach statement and it worked, like when i enter quantity and clicked the "**TotalPrice**" field the price will automatically calculated and displays.

But now i need to update my db with the new entered quantity and total price when i clicked into the "**TotalPrice**" field

I am trying ajax but am not familiar with it

My view

```
                <table class="table">

                        @{
                            int i = 0;

                            foreach (var item in lscart)
                            {
                                i = i + 1;
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CProductID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "pid" + @i } })</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @{
                                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.CImage);
                                var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                                <img src='@imgSrc' style="width:100px; height:100px;" />
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CProductName)</td>
                                    <td>Rs.</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.CPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @id = "cprice" + @i } })</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">

                                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Cquantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = " Qty", @id = "qt" + @i } })


                                        </div>

                                    </td>


                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.CTotalPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @placeholder = " Total Price", @id = "total" + @i, @onclick = "edValueKeyPress(" + @i + ")", @onkeyup = "edValueKeyPress(" + @i + ")" } })

                                        </div>
                                    </td>

                                    <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }


                    </table>
```

My javascript for total price calculation without page refresh

```
<script>
    function edValueKeyPress(i) {


        //alert(i);
        var edValue = document.getElementById("qt" + i);
        var edValue1 = document.getElementById("cprice" + i);
        var s = edValue.value * edValue1.value;
        var t = document.getElementById("total" + i);
        t.value = s;

    }
</script>
```

My ajax code (this is not completed and i dont know where to call this ajax function in my view)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('ready');
        var quantity = document.getElementById("qt" + i);
        var proid = document.getElementById("pid" + i);
        var price = document.getElementById("cprice" + i);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Products/Cartup',
                type: "GET",
                data: { quantity: quantity, proid: proid, price: price },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (rslt) {

                },
                error: function (rslt) {


                }
            });


    })
    </script>
```

My Controler actionmethod

```
 public ActionResult Cartup(int quantity, int proid,float price)
    {
        var Cert = (from cert in db.TBL_Cart where cert.CProductID == proid select cert).FirstOrDefault();
        if (Cert != null)
        {
            int priceint= Convert.ToInt32(price);
            Cert.Cquantity = quantity;
            Cert.CTotalPrice = quantity * priceint;
            db.Entry(Cert).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }


        return View();
    }
```

My DB Table Design

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh9F7.png

My full sourcecode with db

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iegq4kpsoqoue1/backup%20of%20indianhub.zip?dl=0

Controller :ProductsController,
View:cartlist

Comment: My view design

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTWvC.png

Comment: first if you are updating something you need to use a "Post" request. Second you could create an event listener on your input boxes to trigger the ajax call or have a "submit" button to push those changes. Then just add a click handler to that.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to inline saving of your cart on change of `quantity` field?

Comment: Yes i think so inline may be the technical word

Comment: what is `pid` or `proid`? where do you get that from? It's not defined in your cshtml

Comment: Yes inline i think so ..may be inlinr  the technical word

Comment: Oops pid is the product id.. i think i missed to add the html.hidden for fiels...it comes from the cart table.

Comment: Let me edit the post...

Comment: This is a very unsafe design.  Your get action is performing a database update which is generally unwise, and you are allowing for users to manipulate the price via nefarious scripts, relying only on a read only attribute to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just merge the two scripts like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function edValueKeyPress(i) {

    //debugger;
    //alert(i);
    var edValue = document.getElementById("qt" + i);
    var edValue1 = document.getElementById("cprice" + i);
    var s = edValue.value * edValue1.value;
    var t = document.getElementById("total" + i);
    t.value = s;

    var quantity = document.getElementById("qt" + i).value; //alert("quantity" + quantity);
    var proid = document.getElementById("pid" + i).value; //alert(proid);
    var price = document.getElementById("cprice" + i).value; //alert(price);
    //debugger;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: '/Products/Cartup',
        type: "GET",
        data: { quantity: quantity, proid: proid, price: price },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) { alert("success"); },
        error: function (err) { }
    });


}
</script>
```

and i just alter some codes in the view

```
 @{
                            int i = 0;

                            foreach (var item in lscart)
                            {
                                i = i + 1;
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.CProductID, new {  @style = "display: none", @id = "pid" + @i  })</td>
                                    <td>

...................rest of the code is same as in the question
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `id`, add a unique class to each `td`. For example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Cquantity,
   new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "quantity form-control", @placeholder = "Qty" } })
```

Then you can attach a [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) handler to the `quantity` inputs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".quantity").change(function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest("tr"); // get the tr for that row
        var productId = $tr.find('.productID').val(); // get the productID for that row
        var price = $tr.find('.price').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Products/Cartup',
            type: "GET",
            data: { quantity: $(this).val(), proid: productId , price: price },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) { alert("success"); },
            error: function (err) { }
        });
    });
});
```

Some things to consider:

- Your `CTotalPrice` is `readonly`. You don't need to attach any key events to that input.
- No need to give `HiddenFor` element a `td`. You can move it to price `td`
- `db.TBL_Cart where cert.CProductID == proid`: Shouldn't you get the cart by `CartId` instead? I'm not aware of your db structure, but it looks like you're getting the first cart that has a particular prodcut? Not necessarily the cart you want to update.
- Post `cartId`, `productId` and `quantity` to server. Get the price for the product by `productId` in your controller. Update the cart table with total price
- You should use a post method when you;re updating tables

(I hope you're doing this as a personal project to learn. Because otherwise there are many design flaws, your customers will buy everything for free and leave you bankrupt :D)

Answer (score 0):

So as per your question, you want to send an AJAX based request to Your server side code to update your Database and as I can see in your ajax code you are doing AJAX request in Jquery.

I don't know about Jquery but follow my simple example for an AJAX based request.

```
<body>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="totalQuant">
    <input type="text" name="total Amount" id="totalAmt">
    <input type="button" value="TotalPrice" onclick="sendData()">
</body>

<script>
    var req;
    // initialize request object
    function initReq(){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            req= new XMLHttpRequest;
        }
        else if(window.ActiveXObject){
            req= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP);
        }
    }

    //sendData() function defifnation
    function sendData(){
    initReq();
    var amt= document.getElementById("totalAmt").value;
    var qty= document.getElementById("totalQuant").value;

    //creat your url // use escape() if you want encode that field
    var url= "yourURL.abc?totalAmt="+escape(amt)+"&totalQuant="+escape(qty);

    req.open("GET",url);

    // ignore this if you are not sending any response for this request from server
    req.onreadystatechange= processResponse;

    req.send();

    // example with "POST" type request
    var url= "yourURL.abc"
    req.open("POST",url);
    // add this header if you want encode your fields
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    req.send("totalAmt="+amt+"&totalQuant="+qty);

    }
</script>
```